# Silex trailing slash

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I have wrapped Silex around a legacy app. My index.php looks like this:

```
$app->match('/{page}/{action}/{part}/{detail}', function($page, $action, $part, $detail) {
})
    ->value('page', 'backoffice')
    ->value('action', null)
    ->value('part', null)
    ->value('detail', null)
;
```

The problem I'm facing is that there are a lot of URLs that have trailing slashes. For example `http://site/contact/` or `http://site/backoffice/erp/`

When there is a trailing slash the Silex route does not work. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you try to simply add a slash at the end of url pattern? Then it should handle urls either with or without trailing slash.

Comment: I did try this. Then none of the routes work :(

Comment: I've just created a test Silex project on my localhost. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: Could you show me your file? Did you also try it with multiple slashes like my project? `/{page}/{action}/{part}/{detail}/`

Comment: Yes I used your example. There's nothing to show. I've just copied your route and added a slash after `{detail}`.

Comment: Also "does not work" is not good enough of a problem description. Include the error message or describe what's happening.